# Integral revolving around $y=-1$ & $x=-1$

Tags: definite-integrals, volume

Consider the region bounded by these two lines in the first quadrant.

> y=x+1 and y=3-x

Set-Up the integral for the volume of the solid obtained by revolving the region around the lines

> y = -1 and x = -1

Comment: "y=3-y" doesn't make sense to me, Maybe "y=3-x"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, it was a typo.

Comment: no worries you might want to check through and edit your post though

Comment: just made the change

Comment: good stuff. I also don't understand the role of $y=-1$ and $x=-1$ (and I'm assuming you made a typo on line 3 where you wrote $x==1$ rather than $x=-1$?). Plus it's not really clear what you're rotating around. If it's one of these lines which one is it? If not, are you rotating around one of the axes?

Comment: I'm rotating around

Comment: rotating around... what? Can you add all the details to your post.

Comment: Sorry about that, got pulled away from computer yesterday. Updating post now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by understanding what the region looks like, *in detail*. As you say, it looks like an upside-down V. Where is the point of the V? It's at the point where the two lines $y=x+1$ and $y=3-x$ intersect; what is that point? Where is the left edge of the region of integration? The right edge? You will need all of that information to set up the integral for the volume of the solid of revolution.

Also, it's not clear from your original post what the line about which you are revolving is.

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry about that. I've done my best to clarify the question.

Comment: So have you figured out what the region looks like?